# Export CSS File from One Repository and Import it in Another Repository

Tags: css, import, export, github-actions, file-sharing

How to Export CSS File from One Repository and Import Same file in Another Repository.

From one of the article I saw there are 2 ways mentioned. 
either we can make SCSS also export along with js.
or during build, SCSS gets compiled inline with the compiled js component.
Don't have any details on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you're asking many questions at once and only if you find a person that shares nearly the same mind with you, you may find truth in the colleagues answer. Until then why not revisit the tour, browse the [help] and gather improvement suggestion to [edit] your question to a form that can be answered by facts, rather than preference or opinion. Sometimes it can also help to link to other resources to "show" what you mean, for example that _"one article"_ you _"saw"_, what a compiles js component constitutes in your project and those two forms of SCSS exports (A [???] & B [inline]).